# non linear least squares in 3D space in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, least-squares, surface

For 2D space I have used *lsqcurvefit*. But for 3D space I haven't found any easy function.

the function I'm trying to fit has the form something like this:

z = f(x,y) = a+b*x+c*e^(-y/d)

I would like to know if there is any tool box or function for fitting this kind of data the in least square sense. Or can *lsqcurvefit* can be used in some way?

Otherwise I think I have to write something myself. Back to theory reading I guess.

SO, Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem with using lsqcurvefit for this function? It supports functions with multiple input arguments.

Comment: I that case can you tell me how to use it?
I tried to write _xdata_ as a 2D vector. [1 2 3; 2 3 4] hoping it would take inputs as [x;y]. Is there any other way? <I hope I'm explaining it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lsqcurvefit should be able to handle the function given in the question. I don't have a way to verify this code right now, but I believe that it should work:

```
clear variables

f = @(p, x)(p(1)+p(2)*x(:, 1)+p(3)*e.^(-x(:, 2)/p(4)));

xydata = [ 0 0 ; 1 1 ; 2 2 ; 3 3 ];
zdata = [ 0 ; 1 ; 2 ; 3 ];

x = lsqcurvefit(f, [ 0 0 0 0 ], xydata, zdata);
```

Comment: It works. But f should be defined as `f=@(ab,x) (ab(1)+ab(2).*x(:,1)+ab(3).*exp(-x(:,2)/ab(4)))`. Edit it when you have time. Now I see what I did wrong when I tried it. Thanks for the help.